# Hash key and value do not compare equally

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, powershell-7

Why is an integer hash key not an integer? The key is of type KeyCollection even though it was created from a constant integer.

The script to produce this output is below. I will show only the last three (3) command lines. Why is the key not some type of integer?

```
PS C:\> $h.Keys[0].GetType()    # the type of the first and only item in the set of keys is KeyCollection, not an int of some kind

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
False    False    KeyCollection                            System.Object

PS C:\> 1 -eq $h.Keys[0]        # comparing 1 and the key both ways produces different results ???
False
PS C:\> $h.Keys[0] -eq 1
1

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.3.6
```

Here is the script that led to this.

```
$h = @{}
$hi1 = @{1='a';2='b'}   # create a hash
$h.GetType()            # yes, it is a hashtable
$h.Count                # there should be none (0) at this point
$h[1] += @($hi1)        # put an array containing a hash into h
$h[1]                   # check to see that the array containing a hash is in the hash h
$h[1].Count             # there should be one (1) item in the hash
$h[1].GetType()         # the item at hash index 1 should be an array
$h[1][0]                # this is the first and only element in the array
$h[1][0].GetType()      # the first item in the array is a hashtable

$h.Keys                 # there is only one key in the hash
$h.Keys.GetType()       # the type of the Keys object is a KeyCollection
$h.Keys[0]              # the first and only item in the set of keys is 1
$h.Keys[0].GetType()    # the type of the first and only item in the set of keys is KeyCollection, not an int of some kind
1 -eq $h.Keys[0]        # comparing 1 and the key both ways produces different results ???
$h.Keys[0] -eq 1
```

Comment: "Why is an integer hash key not an integer?" you can't index a Key Collection, you would have noticed that if you had added more than one Key to the hash: `$h = @{ 1 = 1; 2 = 2 }; $h.Keys[0]; $h.Keys | % GetType` and they still retain the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this question might have already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552453/powershell-hashtable-keys-property-doesnt-return-the-keys-it-returns-a-keycol)

In case that isn't helpful,

It is my understanding that the KeyCollection object returned by the `Keys` property isn't indexed (nor does it have a built in iterator). So when you try to index into the object with indice 0 PowerShell is just returning the whole object. If you were to try and access indice 1 for instance, you would get nothing back.

You should be able to cast the Keys object to an array by doing something similar to `[Array]$keys_arr = $h.Keys`. You could then access the indices on this array to your hearts content (just be aware that the order of the keys appears to be backwards? I assume that key order is probably undefined in this instance)

Alternatively, if you just needed to access a specific index, you could do `([Array]$h.Keys)[0] -eq ...`

In addition to the SO post linked above, you can also read a bit more about KeyCollections in [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/uyu2gm/trying_to_convert_a_list_of_dictionary_keys/ia6equa/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button).

As for why you are getting different results when flipping the equality statement, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217913/should-null-be-on-the-left-side-of-the-equality-comparison-eq-with-arrays#comment102811959_58217913) by Jeroen Mostert on another answer seems to do a decent job explaining the non-symmetrical nature of -eq in PWSH:

> Equality in PowerShell is not a symmetrical operation. Per the docs: "When the input is a collection of values, the comparison operators return any matching values. If there are no matches in a collection, comparison operators do not return anything." So $null -eq $abc tests if $abc is $null itself, $abc -eq $null finds the $null values in $abc -- and prints nothing, since that's what $null looks like when output. (Compare $abc -eq 7.)

Hope this helps!